# How to run a jupyter notebook programmatically (inside a Sagemaker notebook) from a local environment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I can start/stop Sagemaker notebooks with boto3, but how do run the jupyter notebooks or `.py` scripts inside?

This is something I'll run from a local environment or lambda (but that's no problem).

**Start Sagemaker notebook instance:**

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

client.start_notebook_instance(
    NotebookInstanceName='sagemaker-notebook-name'
)
```

[docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.start_notebook_instance)

In the UI I would just click "Open Jupyter", then run a notebook or a `.py` script inside it.

[image]

But I want to do it programmatically with boto3 or other.

My file inside is called `lemmatize-input-data.ipynb`.

This must be possible but I'm unsure how?

**I also tried:**

In a "start notebook" lifecycle configuration script, after creating a simpler test file called `test_script.ipynb` to be certain it wasn't something advanced in my jupyter notebook that caused the error.

```
set -e

jupyter nbconvert --execute test_script.ipynb
```

But got the error:

> [NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern 'test_script.ipynb' matched no files

Comment: did any of the suggestions work for you? I am also facing the same issue but it's not currently working for me.

Answer (score 3):

You have the correct approach of executing the notebook inside a Lifecycle Configuration script. The issue is that the working directory of the script is "/" whereas the Jupyter server starts up from */home/ec2-user/SageMaker*.

So, if you modify the script to address the absolute path to the notebook file and it should work.

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/lemmatize-input-data.ipynb
```

Thanks for using Amazon SageMaker!

Comment: Hi Jaipreet - This gives me the below error. Any idea, please? : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 270, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 664, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 340, in start
...

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to look into [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill). It copies and runs a template notebook, using nbconvert under the hood. What I have found the main benefit of papermill to be is you can easily parameterize notebooks and pass in the parameters via a python dictionary. The copies of the template then maintain a history of what was executed and the results.

Your code would be something like:

```
import papermill as pm

pm.execute_notebook(
   'lemmatize-input-data.ipynb',
   'lemmatize-input-data-####.ipynb'
)
```

With #### being something like datetime.now() or whatever you would like to differentiate the notebooks as they execute.

Since notebooks are intended to be living documents, you want to limit the number of external dependencies that would have breaking changes if the notebook changes and you need to re-run as of a point in time. Papermill addresses this by making a snapshot of what was executed at that time.

**Update** for a little more background:

I would update the jupyter notebook to contain the python code instead of the script. The notebook will execute cell by cell and act just like script. This also allows you to print and display intermediate and final values within the notebook, if needed. When papermill copies and executes the template notebook, all of the output will be displayed and saved within the notebook. This is handy for any graphs that have been generated.

Papermill also has functionality that will then aggregate data across notebooks. See [here](https://pythonawesome.com/a-tool-for-parameterizing-and-analyzing-jupyter-notebooks/) for a good article summarizing papermill in general. Papermill was designed by Netflix and they have a good post about the philosophy behind it [here](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/scheduling-notebooks-348e6c14cfd6), in which they reference machine learning.

All this being said, papermill can be used to easily document each step of training your machine learning model in sagemaker. Then using the aggregation capabilities of papemrill, you can graphically see over time how your model changed.

Comment: This is cool. But can you explain how this helps run a jupyter notebook / python script in sagemaker? I'm a bit of a newb.

Comment: Added more info to post. Please read through some of the links I have included for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look [here](https://clouderizer.com/jupyter-notebook-deployment/). This can deploy your Jupyter Notebook as a serverless function and then you can invoke it using the REST endpoint.